# How to render .obj files in a non-euclidean way?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, programming, noneuclidean-geometry

Apologies in advance if this question is misguided or foolish; I'm learning. My goal is to write a non-euclidean renderer in the Rust programming language, and I'm wondering if anyone could tell me if this would theoretically work. I want to be able to import a scene of objects and render them in curved space. In [the paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=8a6891c95d6e6ef480460b5af67c69cfb7d0ceea) I'm reading, Jeff Weeks defines that, for rotation and translation,

[image]

As I understand, a 4D Hypersphere is defined by the formula

[image]

Does this imply I can render spherical space by replacing the *w*?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.